# Customize UI when a survey has been served

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I've been trying to customize the survey that is received from Qualtrics so that I may display it the way I want. The Creatives don't give enough customization to do that, so I've been thinking that I may be able to serve the survey using a Custom HTML Creative, extract what's inside and serving it on my own container.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Is there anything that I should look out for, or a better way to do things?

To be more clear on what I am trying to do: I am currently getting the survey using a Custom HTML creative and site intercept. The survey lands on a div tag that I need to modify so that the entire survey is displayed instead of a scrollable section.

Comment: To make sure I understand, you are trying to modify the visual appearance of the survey? Have you tried including custom css to achieve what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to modify more than what the custom CSS allows, I believe. I am trying to, for example, accommodate the height of where the survey is displayed based on the length of the survey.

Comment: Any chance for a visual display of what you're trying to achieve? I've found that ALMOST anything is possible given the tools available and enough time to play with it. It's possible yours is an edge case, but it's always worth making sure before you take the difficult route.

Comment: On second read, it appears you are embedding this survey in another webpage and want to be able to modify that page based on qualtrics information, is that correct?